# Using a Windows Service as 3rd-party application server for GCM

Tags: android, web-services, windows-services, google-cloud-messaging

Currently, I have an Android app and a Web Service written in C# using Visual Studio. Web service is published to an IIS. Android app makes calls to the web service to retrieve data from a MS SQL Server DB.

Furthermore, I have a Windows Service that responds to certain changes in the data of MS SQL Server DB. Currently, the Windows Service is capable to firing off an email when data in certain tables in MS SQL server DB is updated.

What I am interested in achieving now is to use Google Cloud Messaging to implement notifications in the Android app. So for example, I would like for the Windows Service to be able to fire off a message to GCM Connection Servers and therefore talk to the Android app.

As you can see all of my back-end is Microsoft technologies. I was wondering if anybody has experience connecting the different stacks that I am using. Or if not, if anybody has a solid workable idea as how I can achieve what I want o achieve with the least amount of change in the technologies I am using?

Specifically, Android documentation talks about 3rd-party application server, that I would like to replace with with my Windows Service. But I don't know how. Any insight from prior experience or at least suggestion of a solid path to achieve my goal is very much appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the documentation? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Comment: Yes, I have. And the part that I am stuck now is the 3rd Party Application Server that the documentation talks about.

Comment: Stuck at what exactly? Do you want to know how to connect you back end MS techs to the server or how to communicate with GCM through 3rd party server?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I can use the Windows Service that I have as the 3rd-party application server. If I can, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just push notifications to android devices then it's enough:
- android application has to be able to pass the device RegistrationID (for example, through your Web Service).
- your service has to be able to send POST requests to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send in order to send the messages.

If you need some CCS features then you should implement 3rd-party application server using one of XMPP libraries for .net. It is also possible with Windows Service.